# Java JDBC Template: Insert into Not Null Columns with Default Values

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a Microsoft SQL Server table, with a CustomerId Required column, that defaults to 5 if no value provided. The table has over 50 columns. Application is using Java Spring Boot namedParameterJdbcTemplate.

How do I efficiently Insert into SQL table from Java class? In following code, if no customerId is provided in Java Dto class, It inserts null, then gives SQL Error `"Cannot Insert into Not Null Column"` .

1. Alternative is write `ISNULL(:CustomerId, 5)`,  however table has multiple columns like this, and Java is expected to know SQL default value at an application level, which is not ideal. We could use InformationSchema table to find default values, however that will be messy for 20 columns.
2. Another option is dynamically edit the sql const string, to have not null default values at end, and dynamically alter string to append those with insert-values provided, add to string if value provided, exclude from string if not provided relying on default.

Does Java JDBC template have a library function to handle this? Otherwise I will resort to workarounds above.

**SQL:**

```
create table ProductSales
(
    CustomerId       int    default 5        not null,
```

**Java:**

```
public class ProductSalesDto
{
    ...
    public int customerId;
    ...
}

MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("CustomerId", productSalesDto.customerId);

String INSERT_PRODUCT_SALES = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT_SALES" +
        "(TotalAmount, CustomerId, ..., " +
        "values (:TotalAmount, :CustomerId, ...) 

      
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_PRODUCT_SALES, parameters);
```

Comment: if there is no value (you want to use the default), then don't include that column in the insert query.

Comment: hi @RandyCasburn sometimes user provides value in Java dto, other times they don't

Comment: that's what logical expressions are intended to solve

Comment: hi @RandyCasburn not sure how to incorporate that in Java jdbc template

Comment: You can dynamically pass column names using `SimpleJdbcInsert`

Comment: hi @NavnathJadhav so you are saying using jdbcInsert rather than question objective  jdbcTemplate? Can I derive jdbcinsert from template? that is two different objects

Comment: Yes - Use `SimpleJdbcTemplate` rather than `JdbcTemplate` - [SimpleJdbcInsert](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate#1-simplejdbcinsert) along with a call to [simpleJdbcInsert.usingColumns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch13s05.html) - just leave off the `CustomerID` when specifying columns to insert. (see 13.5.3)

Comment: see our company prefers namedParameterJdbcTemplate in its repos, is there anyway to get SimpleJdbcTemplate from namedParamers? cc @RandyCasburn